# Avoid CORS preflight check in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cors

in my view I have

```
<%= link_to "Angebot als PDF", redirect_to_offer_pdf_offer_path(offer, project_id: @project.id), method: :get, class:"dropdown-item" %>
```

The `redirect_to_offer_pdf` action in the offers controller:

```
url = get_url_on_other_host()

if url
  redirect_to url, allow_other_host: true
end
```

When I click on the link I get this error in the browser console:

```
Access to fetch at '<other_host_url>' (redirected from '<the_action_url') from origin '<my_host>' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

How can I "set the request's mode to 'no-cors'"?

Why is CORS check even necessary for a simple redirect? I thought it is only necessary for DELETE or PUT requests.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [rack-cors gem](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) to handle CORS.
It lets you create an initializer where you allow your request settings

```
# config/initializers/cors.rb

Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :patch, :put]
  end
end
```

Comment: That is something that must be done on the redirect target, right?